# Running D3.js example with own data doesn't work

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, observable, graphviz

I would like to build the following graph from the D3.js library:

https://observablehq.com/@pydanny/bjj-standing-flow-1

Now I want to fetch the data for the graph from my database and put it into a JSON file (I did that). The content of the JSON file should be passed to the graph. This is the original code in which the data is passed to the graph:

```
main.variable(observer()).define(["dot"], function(dot){
    return (
          dot` digraph G {
              node [shape=box];
              Mount [color = red]  SideMount [color = red]  Gaurd [color = red]  NorthSouth [color = red] Standing [color = red];
              Standing -> SnapDown;
              SnapDown -> OsotoGeri [style=dashed];
              SnapDown -> SideClinch [style=dashed];
         }`
      )
   });
```

I have changed it (to pass data from json-file) as follows:

```
  main.variable(observer()).define(["dot"], function(dot){
    return (d3.json("data.json").then(function (data){
          var result = data;
          var arrayLength = result.edges.length;
          var resultDataString = dot + "digraph G{ \n";
          resultDataString = resultDataString + "node [shape=box] \n";
          resultDataString = resultDataString + "Mount [color = red]  SideMount [color = red]  Gaurd [color = red]  NorthSouth [color = red] Standing [color = red]; \n";
          for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            var arr = result.edges[i];
            resultDataString =  resultDataString + " " + arr[0] + " -> " + arr[1] + " ;\n ";
          }
          resultDataString = resultDataString + " }";
          return resultDataString;
        })
    )

});
```

Content of the JSON-File:

```
{
  "edges": [
    [
      "Burpee With Push Up",
      "Push Up"
    ],
    [
      "Burpee With Push Up",
      "Squat Jump"
    ],
    [
      "Squat Jump",
      "Squat"
    ],
    [
      "Squat Jump",
      "Two Footed Jump"
    ],
    [
      "Two Footed Jump",
      "Stand"
    ],
    [
      "Push Up",
      "Plank"
    ],
    [
      "Plank",
      "Lay"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I read the content of the JSON-File, convert it to the given format and returned it. But I don't get the graph, only this:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what my mistake is?

Comment: Can you attach a js fiddle link or something ?

Comment: @IsettyRavitejakumar This is not possible because there are too many files.